# Opt group dropdown in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to display a hierarchical dropdown in ionic like the below image
[image]

and i have tried select with optgroup but it display like this [image]

not matched with designing

Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciate!

Comment: you can use https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.